# MySQL - Select only non - numeric values from varchar column

Tags: mysql

```
create table mixedvalues (value varchar(50));

insert into mixedvalues values ('100');
insert into mixedvalues values ('ABC100');
insert into mixedvalues values ('200');
insert into mixedvalues values ('EFEA200');
insert into mixedvalues values ('300');
insert into mixedvalues values ('AAFASF300');
insert into mixedvalues values ('400');
insert into mixedvalues values ('AERG400');
insert into mixedvalues values ('500');
insert into mixedvalues values ('AGE500');
```

i want to select only non-numeric(alpha numeric) values, i.e ABC100,EFEA200,AAFASF300,AERG400,AGE500.

i have the code for selecting numeric values, i.e 100,200....

```
SELECT * 
FROM mixedvalues 
WHERE value REGEXP '^[0-9]+$';
```

Please help me,iam a beginner.

Comment: Do the letters `A`, `B`, and `C` always appear in each non-numeric record?

Comment: You can use LIKE keyword for this WHERE value like '%200'

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen no, it maynot be always ABC, any random alphabet

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The regex `[a-zA-Z]` should only fire true if a value contains at least one letter.

```
SELECT * 
FROM mixedvalues 
WHERE value REGEXP '[a-zA-Z]';   -- or REGEXP '[[:alpha:]]'
```

Comment: "non numeric" does not mean only containing letters. You also could have other chars...

Comment: @CyrilJacquart The OP mentioned `i want to select only non-numeric(alpha numeric) values` ... I interpret this, along with the sample data provided, that all inputs would be strictly alphanumeric.

Answer (score 6):

The `REGEXP '^[^0-9]+$`' selects all non numeric characters

```
SELECT state
FROM `enquiry`
GROUP BY state
HAVING state REGEXP '^[^0-9]+$'
```

Comment: This did not seem to catch special characters for some reason....

Comment: This will select only the ones that have non numeric at start. Use '[^0-9]' if you want to search for non-numeric anywhere in string